# Can't run Qt application under UWP kit

Tags: qt, windows-runtime, qtquickcontrols2

My app is Qt Quick Controls 2 based app. Qt 5.7.1, Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015.

Desktop 32bit version works fine.

But when I switch to **Qt 5.7.1 for Universal Windows Platform 32bit** kit, it fails to run with the following error:

```
winrtrunner --device 0 --start --stop --install --wait 0 --profile appx C:/Work/Source/build-MusicPlayer-Qt_5_7_1_for_Universal_Windows_Platform_32bit-Release/bin/player.exe
qt.winrtrunner: Using the Appx profile.
qt.winrtrunner: Failed to activate application: 0x8027025b "The app didn't start."
Error while executing the WinRT Runner Tool: Process crashed
```

It states [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/50638/start-application-on-winrt) that some dependency is missing. I've checked it using Dependency Walker and it seems that all the required DLLs are in the application's folder. I've also tried to copy just all the files from Qt kit installation into app's dir.

My application consists of one main executable and three .DLL files. I've launched windeployqt for the each of them. Tried both debug and release versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on Windows 10, Qt 5.8 (also 5.7), Windows Runtime 64bit VC2015.

This topic was opened on Qt website here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/73272/qt-5-7-for-winrt-and-dynamic-libraries, but it did not help in my case :(. I opened a new topic here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/75424/cannot-start-qt-quick-winrt-application

Comment: I've created a bug report here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-17622

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.

You need to recompile all static / dynamic libraries that your application uses for Windows 10 SDK. The issue is that you need to use WinRT dll's which provide sandbox environment instead of "normal" Windows libraries. Windows Store applications require that.

In my case I was using zip static library (zlibstat.lib) with Quazip static library (quazip.lib), compiled in Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012.

Instead, I used Qt zip, as Qt provides zip library inside QtCore.dll, (just use #include  instead of #include "zlib.h") and recompiled Quazip as a static library for Windows 10 SDK.